# Why does a nullptr terminated array passed to function through ***char loose the termination element?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Note 1: I am not looking for *different* solutions to the problem at hand. I'm curious about what actually is happening here.

Note 2: I'm doing this in c++ context, but am assuming that this also applies to C, hence the C tag. (apart from the representation of a null pointer)

This is about c-strings and access to original from a function. I'll use argv and argc to illustrate that the array should be nullptr terminated. I declare them like this:

```
int argc = 1;
char **argv = (char**) malloc( (argc + 1) * sizeof(char*) );
argv[0] = (char*)"argument 0";
argv[1] = nullptr;
```

If I declare a function like this: `func1(int &f_argc, char **f_argv)` I can access all elements inside the function scope, including `f_argv[f_argc]`, which is `nullptr`, but I cannot modify the original `argv` to point to a different address as f_argv in the function is a value passed copy of the original pointer. It has a different address in memory.

If I declare the function like this instead: `func2(int &f_argc, char ***f_argv)`, I can access the original `argv` through `*f_argv` in the function, but the last element (which should be `nullptr`) is cut off. This means that if I try to check for the terminating `nullptr` inside the function, I try to access an element outside the range of the array, resulting in a core dump at runtime.

Q1: Why is `f_argv` cut off when reaching the `nullptr` in func2, but not in func1?

Q2: Is there a way to get write access to the original `argv` from within the function, without removing the terminator?

Edit: (added code to show what I mean)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void func1(int &f_argc, char **f_argv) {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cout << "    In function:" << endl;
    cout << "    argv passed as **f_argv" << endl;
    cout << "    f_argv = " << f_argv << " , &f_argv = " << &f_argv << endl;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < f_argc; pos++) {
        if (f_argv[pos] != nullptr) {
            cout << "    f_argv[" << pos << "] = \"" << f_argv[pos] << "\"" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "    f_argv is prematurely terminated" << endl;
        }
    }

    if (f_argv[f_argc] == nullptr) {
        cout << "    f_argv is correctly terminated" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "    f_argv[" << f_argc << "] = \"" << f_argv[f_argc] << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "    f_argv is not terminated" << endl;
    }

    // Intention is to copy argv here, add elements, terminate it with
    // nullptr and change original argv to point to copy. This wouldn't
    // work in this function, as &f_argv != &argv.

    return;
}

void func2(int &f_argc, char ***f_argv) {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cout << "    In function:" << endl;
    cout << "    array passed as ***f_argv" << endl;
    cout << "    f_argc = " << f_argc
         << " , &f_argc = " << &f_argc << endl;
    cout << "    *f_argv = " << *f_argv
         << " , f_argv = " << f_argv << endl;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < f_argc; pos++) {
        cout << "    about to check: "
             << "if (*f_argv[" << pos << "] != nullptr)" << endl;
        if (*f_argv[pos] != nullptr) {
            cout << "    *f_argv[" << pos << "] = \""
                 << *f_argv[pos] << "\"" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "    *f_argv is prematurely terminated" << endl;
        }
    }

    if (*f_argv[f_argc] == nullptr) {
        cout << "    *f_argv is correctly terminated" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "    *f_argv[" << f_argc << "] = \""
             << *f_argv[f_argc] << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "    *f_argv is not terminated" << endl;
    }

    // Intention is to copy argv here, add elements, terminate it with
    // nullptr and change original argv to point to copy.

    return;
}



// --------------------------------------------

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    int argc=1;
    char **argv = (char**) malloc( (argc + 1) * sizeof(char*) );
    argv[0] = (char*)"argument 0";
    argv[1] = nullptr;

    cout << "Before function call" << endl;
    cout << "argv = " << argv << " , &argv = " << &argv << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i] != nullptr) {
            cout << "argv[" << i << "] = \"" << argv[i] << "\"" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "argv is prematurely terminated" << endl;
        }
    }
    if (argv[argc] == nullptr) {
        cout << "argv is correctly terminated" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "argv[" << argc << "] = \"" << argv[argc] << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "argv is not terminated" << endl;
    }

    // run one of these
    //func1(argc, argv);
    func2(argc, &argv);

    free(argv);

    return 0;

}
```

If running func2, running the program results in a core dump at this line:

```
if (*f_argv[f_argc] == nullptr) {
```

Comment: How do you call `func2()`?

Comment: Is that nullptr as in Microsoft's C++ for .NET, and not the normal NULL pointer?

Comment: Did you write `*f_argv[1]` when you really want `(*f_argv)[1]`?

Comment: It seems to me that you really need to have posted the code related to "*if I try to check for the terminating nullptr inside the function*", since that is what is crashing!

Comment: I added code to explain

Comment: @T.C. I tried that previously without effect, but there must have been some other differences then. This time it was the solution. Ouch...

Comment: @T.C. Could you change your comment to an answer, so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough levels of indirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscript operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator. `*f_argv[f_argc]` is `*(f_argv[f_argc])`. What you want is `(*f_argv)[f_argc]`.

Since you are using C++, you should consider taking `f_argv` by reference - `void f(int &f_argc, char **& f_argv);`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and the correct use of reference to pointer.